# Why does Browserify include package.json for some NPM packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, browserify, babeljs

[image]

Im using gulp and browserify to create a single bundle js file, but for a few packages their package.json along with full local file paths is included in the final file. Why is this?

I have "fullPaths: false" set for browserify in my gulp task.

My package.json (for gulp):

```
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"babelify": "^7.3.0",
"browserify": "^13.1.0"
```

Thanks

Comment: For [numerous reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6680611), including screenshots in questions is discouraged. Could you replace the screenshot with a code block that contains the snippet from your bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full paths are in the `package.json`. The full paths are there not because of Browserify, but because NPM adds them when the modules are installed.

The `package.json` file that's in the bundle appears to be for the `useragent` module and is included because that module has required it (i.e. `require("./package.json")`). It has done this to facilitate the reporting of the version that's specified in the `package.json` file.

You can see the `require` call [here](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/useragent/blob/v2.0.7/index.js#L598).